# $P(X \le 0)=1$ implies $E(X) \le 0$

Tags: probability, random-variable

*Show that $P(X \le 0)=1$ implies $E(X) \le 0$*

***What I attempted:-***

Consider $X$ to be a discrete random variable.  Now, we have 
\begin{equation} \begin{aligned} E(X) &=\sum_{x:x\le 0} x P(X=x)+\sum_{x:x > 0} x P(X=x) \\  &=\sum_{x:x\le 0} x P(X=x) \qquad \mbox{[Because, If} \quad x>0, P(X=x)=0 ]\\ &\le \sum_{x:x\le 0} 0. P(X=x) \qquad \mbox{[we are summing over all} \quad x \le 0] \\ &=0 \end{aligned} \end{equation}

Similar argument could be made if $X$ is continuous.

Is my procedure correct? Is there any difference between these two statements $(1)$ $P(X\le 0)=1$ and $(2)$$X\le 0$?

Comment: I can't see any mistake in your procedure... Of course, the two statements are rigourously the same...

Comment: For non-discrete random variables there is a difference: it is possible for $X \gt 0$ even when $\Pr(X\le 0)=1.$  As a non-trivial example, consider an infinite sequence of flips $\omega$ of a fair coin.  Define $X(\omega)$ to be $1$ if the limiting proportion of heads in $\omega$ does not equal $1/2$ and otherwise let $X(\omega)=-1.$  Although there are a great number of sequences in the event $X=1,$ the [Weak Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) asserts the chance of this event is zero.

Comment: Just to be precise, the result you're asserting is the Strong Law of Large Numbers, not the WLLN. You're claiming an 'almost sure' result, which is not what the Weak Law gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a more general demonstration of this result (where $X$ can be continuous or discrete or a mixture) by expressing the expectation using the [Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration).

If $\mathbb{P}(X \leqslant 0) = 1$ then we have $F(x) = 1$ for all $x > 0$, which gives Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\mu_F(0,\infty) = 0$.  Using 
Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration we therefore have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X) = \int \limits_\mathbb{R} x dF(x) 
&= \int \limits_{x \leqslant 0} x dF(x) + \int \limits_{x > 0} x dF(x) \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{x \leqslant 0} x dF(x) + 0 \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{x \leqslant 0} x dF(x) \leqslant 0, \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

were the transition to the second line occurs because $\mu_F(0,\infty) = 0$ and the final inequality occurs because the integrand is non-positive.

Answer (score 0):

A random variable $X$ is said to be integrable if $\mathbb E[X^+]$ and $\mathbb E[X^-]$ are both finite, where
\begin{align}
X^+ &:= \max\{X,0\}\\
X^- &:= \max\{-X,0\}.
\end{align}
Then by definition, $$\mathbb E[X] := \mathbb E[X^+] - \mathbb E[X^-]. $$
If $\mathbb P(X\leqslant 0)=1$, then $\mathbb E[X^+]=0$ (since $X^+\geqslant0$ a.s.), so $\mathbb E[X]=-\mathbb E[X^-]<0$.